# How do I insert an underlined ordinal indicator, if the font does not have that glyph?

Tags: fonts, text-decorations

Basically what I want to do is underline ordinal indicators ª and º, because some fonts do not underline them.

Answer (score 13):

You could use the TeX/LaTeX command `\b` to typeset a short "bar" below the letter in question.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ula}{\textsuperscript{\b{a}}} % "underlined a in superscript mode"
\newcommand{\ulo}{\textsuperscript{\b{o}}}
\begin{document}
N\ula, N\ulo
\end{document}
```

Comment: The \b command doesn't seem to work with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Joseph - Could you be a bit more specific about the claim that the "`\b` command doesn't seem to work with XeLaTeX". I encounter no problems when I compile the above example using XeLaTeX, with or without the `fontspec` package being loaded as well. Do you maybe load a special font?

Comment: It doesn't work with fontspec with pretty much any font -- Minion, Myriad, you name it. It generates a dummy character to the right side of the superscript.

Comment: @Joseph - You may have stumbled onto a bug in `fontspec`, in both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Edit: I found fonts which work with Mico's command (for instance, Brill), but still, the underline doesn't feel right: I'd like it to get closer to the letter. Is that possible?